# Is the word χιραϲ used in the Codex Sinaiticus as a proper noun to mean Hira or as another part of speech to mean hands?

Tags: greek, greek-translation

Codex Sinaiticus gives the following rendition of [Isa. 29:12](http://www.codexsinaiticus.org/en/manuscript.aspx?book=14&chapter=29&lid=en&side=r&verse=12&zoomSlider=0):

> και δοθηϲεται το βιβλιον τουτο ειϲ **χιραϲ** ανθρωπου · μη επιϲταμενου γραμʼματα ˙ και ερι αυτω · αναγνωθι ταυτα και ερι . ουκ αιπιϲταμαι γραμʼματα

Is χιραϲ = χεῖρας?

Is *χιραϲ* used in the codex as a proper noun to mean Hira or as another part of speech to mean hands? Do codices differ on the grammar on this matter?

Comment: "αιπιϲταμαι" is comically misspelled. Why shouldn't there be more misspelled words?

Answer (score 7):

I would say "hands" without a doubt.

The "standard" rendition of the first half is, very literally:

> καὶ δοθήσεται τὸ βιβλίον τοῦτο
> *And this book will be given*
>
> εἰς χεῖρας ἀνθρώπου
> *into [the] hands of a person*
>
> μὴ ἐπισταμένου γράμματα…
> *[who is] not knowing letters…*

Or, using more idiomatic English, "and this book will be placed in the hands of one who cannot read". (It's entirely reasonable Greek, it just sounds awkward when I try to keep every Greek word intact in English.)

Given the context, *ειϲ χιραϲ ανθρωπου* has to mean "into [the] *chiras* of a person". Using a proper noun here, "into the Hira of a person", makes less sense than assuming a simple mistake—swapping *ι* for *ει* is an extremely common error from the Koinë period onward, since they were pronounced identically.

EDIT: Google has led me to a very…eccentric…theory that this passage is meant to say "will be given to a man at Mount Hira". I'm guessing you've found that too, and that's where this question is coming from.

But I'm quite confident that's not the case here:

- *Εἰς* very clearly means "into", indicating a direction of motion; I've never seen a situation where it can mean "at" or "in".
- Proper names, especially foreign ones, almost always take a definite article—which is lacking here.
- *Ἀνθρώπου* is very clearly in the genitive, and *εἰς* always requires an accusative.
- The Greek letter χ isn't generally used for an H-like sound in the Septuagint: look at 2 Samuel 23:26, where the name "Hira" is written *Εἴρας*. Using χ where it doesn't belong could be scribal error, but if so it's not anywhere near as common as *ει* → *ι*.

EDIT 2: As brianpck points out in the comments, confusing *ει* and *ι* happens just a few words later, where this codex has *ερι* for standard *ἐρεῖ* "shall say" (to read this).

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the diphthong change happens just a few words afterwards too: ερει -> ερι

Comment: @brianpck Right, which is why you also get things like Δαυιδ v. Δαυειδ. This substitution is very common in the Codex Sinaiticus.